# Error: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Tags: python, numpy, math, pygrib

```
output=np.column_stack((
L1.values.ravel(),
L2.values.ravel(),
L3.values.ravel(),
L8.values.ravel(),
L9.values.ravel(),
L10.values.ravel(),
L11.values.ravel(),
WCSFC,
WCUPPER,
TCSFC,
DCSFC,
TCUPPER,
Tornado,
L1.latlons()[0].ravel(),
L1.latlons()[1].ravel()))

output = np.concatenate(map(pointInBox, output), output, axis=1)


np.savetxt(f, output, fmt="%f", delimiter=',')
f.close()
```

Returned:

```
return _nx.concatenate(arrays, 1)
ValueError: all the input array   dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Comment: Your `concatenate` expression looks wrong.  Its arguments are supposed to be a list (of arrys) and an axis parameter.  Instead it has a `map`, an array, and axis.  It almost looks like you are trying to apply the concatenate in a mapped loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are stacking 1D arrays as columns to make a 2D array. So, all of the arrays passed to `concatenate` must have shape `(n, )`, where the value of `n` *must* be the same for all your arguments. Clearly, in your case this does not happen. Find which argument(s) doesn't fit and remove it.